# Using Logstash for indexing items from Cassandra to Solr

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, logstash, elastic-stack

I want to understand the reality of using `Logstash` as a mid tunnel in order to read `Items` **(Not logs)** from `Cassandra` in order indexing it in `Solr`

Is this a good approach for `Production` environment? Is it secure? or better to use a normal approach like `Cassandra - SQS - Consumers/Crons - Solr`?

Comment: it's too broad question - how much data you have, do you need to sync everything, or only the new items, do you need to handle deletes, etc.?

Comment: You should consider using elassandra, which has elasticsearch on top of cassandra instead of using logstash.

Comment: @AlexOtt actually I'll need to sync up everything

Comment: @AlexTbk My concern about  Elassandra that the community edition doesn't support SSL encryption between the nodes , and it will cost more for the enterprise edition .. That's why I was thinking about using `Cassandra` + `Solr` with a mid layer like SQS and consumers

Comment: Do you really need SSL between nodes? In our case they are deployed on an internal network / gcp which should not be accessible from outside. Inter-DC sync is done via VPN tunnels

Comment: I would say that this is a complex task that isn't solvable easily with just one tool. That's why DSE Search & Elasssandra exists...

Comment: @AlexTbk, just for my understanding, why are you hesitating to recommend `logstash`? this gets the job done easily I think even with `SSL` . Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Because you will need to handle the sync manually, if I understood correctly. You can replicate but you can't delete properly. You need to take care of failing nodes and all the edge cases

Comment: @AlexOtt 
@AlexTbk  Thank you . I got your points there , I was leaning to use Solr as a search engine and fully opensource , but after trading it off with Elastic stack (Open source) , I'm feeling that it would be better to use Elasic stack through `Elassandra` , and I might adapt with the missing commercial features . Do you agree with me on "ELasticSearch" is a good choose for long term ?

Comment: We use it (elassandra) succesfully in production > 1 year . I strongly advice to use the latest versions as there were issues with indexing maps which has been solved